# Voltage/Current phase shift caused by capacitor/inductor

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor

Im trying to understand exactly how a capacitor and inductor affect the RC and RL circuits and am not sure exactly what is correct. When I look online for phase shifts for these components it mostly talks about *Current Leads Voltage by 90 degrees* in a capacitor and *Current Lags Voltage by 90 degrees* in an inductor, which I understand. Where I'm not sure is how do we analyze the voltage phase shift when we add a capacitor, and the current phase shift when we add an inductor.

I have a an RC circuit setup and have notice that the original (pink) voltage is leading the RC (yellow) voltage, which makes sense as a capacitor resists change in voltage. I am having difficulty finding the mathematics to calculate this phase shift, which I find is different when I used different frequencies. Also, what is happening to the current (I don't have a shunt resistor yet to show a current waveform on my scope)? If the current leads the voltage by 90 degrees, it would lead me to believe that the original and RC current would have the same phase shift from each other.

Then with an inductor things would just be the opposite, the original voltage will lag the RL voltage by some phase (again couldn't find the math for this), and same with the original vs RL current by that same phase.

To sum it up:

1. What is the mathematics on calculating the phase shift of voltage for a capacitor/ current on an inductor?
2. Is my thoughts on what is happening to the voltage and current for each component correct?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this part of an EE lab assignment?

Comment: @VoltageSpike no this is me passing time lol, otherwise I would go to a professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vout = (Vs * Xc)/(R + Xc) where the angle of Vs is 0 degrees (the reference), the angle of Xc is -90 degrees and the angle of the resistance is 0 degrees.

The angles of the impedances represent the phase of the voltage with respect to the current.

You'll need to convert the denominator to rectangular form to do the addition and then convert back to polar form to do the division, or you could start with the denominator in rectangular form as R - jXc before converting it to polar form ready for the division.

If you make Vs = R = Xc = 1 then Vout will equal 0.707 at an angle of -45 degrees that is to say the output is lagging the input by 45 degrees at the cut-off (-3dB) frequency.

Now do the same for (Vs * R)/(R + Xc) to find the phase and voltage across the resistor with respect to the source voltage and you will get 0.707 at an angle of +45 degrees.

Once you have mastered those calculations you can vary the frequency to adjust the value of Xc and see how it adjusts the voltages across the components and the phases relative to Vs. Note though that there will always be 90 degrees between the voltage across the resistor and the voltage across the capacitor and the current will always be in phase with the voltage across the resistor.

You will find that as frequency varies, one component's phasor will move closer to the input voltage's phasor as the other component's phasor moves further from it thereby maintaining the 90 degrees angle between the resistance phasor and the capacitive reactance phasor.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the mathematics on calculating the phase shift of voltage for a capacitor/ current on an inductor?

Basically you have to learn circuit analysis. The math isn't difficult, but explaining and, more importantly, justifying it is beyond the scope of this forum.  There are a lot of resources available on the web. The general progression of topics in a first-year electronics course is:

- KCL, KVL
- solving simple DC circuits
- circuit analysis with differential equations
- solving AC circuits with phasors

Once you get to this point you'll have the tools to figure out exactly what's going on in these circuits.

> If the current leads the voltage by 90 degrees, it would lead me to believe that the original and RC current would have the same phase shift from each other.
> ...
> Is my thoughts on what is happening to the voltage and current for each component correct?

The 90-degree phase shift is true for any single capacitor or inductor in a circuit. But when you look at the voltage/current relationship for two components in series then it's a more complicated story and the phasor arithmetic will tell you what the phase shift is.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the mathematics on calculating the phase shift of voltage for a capacitor/ current on an inductor?

Consider the circuit below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDakPW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage across the capacitor is just \$V_C=V_{in} \$. The relationship between voltage across and current through a capacitor is
$$i_C=C \frac{dV_c}{dt} $$
Assume that \$V_{in}=V_C=\sin(\omega t) \$, the current through the capacitor then becomes
$$i_C=\omega C \cdot\cos(\omega t) = \omega C \cdot\sin(\omega t+90^\circ) $$
The current has \$+90^\circ \$ phase shift with respect to the voltage. The current *leads* the voltage by 90 degrees.

A similar calculation can be made for an inductor.

> Is my thoughts on what is happening to the voltage and current for each component correct?

By the looks of it, yes.